# GDB monitor inside TMUX garbled

Tags: c, terminal, gdb

I was debugging in terminal using gdb, and I typed in`layout src`,then I entered the UI mode.
Most of the time, it worked fine, but sometimes, the whole terminal text code got mixed.(I post the picture below.).
[image]

what's more, sometimes I typed in some shell command in gdb like `!pmap <pid>`, its output's format was also strange.
[image]

I tried to set TERM to screen-256color but it doesn't work.

Comment: I can't post my picture, sad.

Comment: Is it because that gdb output and my program output mixed?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it in some sense.
I redirect the output of my program to another tty.

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you make this redirection on your program to work inside gdb tui mode?